# How to clear user uploaded images if the limit of files exceeded in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, image

I have a simple form where a user can upload multiple images. I only want the user to upload 4 images at once, so I did the following:

```js
$("#myfile").on("change", function() {
    if ($("#myfile")[0].files.length > 4) {
        alert("You can select only 4 images");
    } 
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="myfile" class="form-control" name="pimage[]" multiple="multiple">
```

This gives an alert when the user uploads more than 4 images but doesn't stop them from submitting the form.

Can anyone please tell me how to clear the user uploaded images if the limit exceeds or disable the submit button?

Comment: as you said disable the button....add the disabled attribute.... that's one strategy....

Comment: @DimitrisPapageorgiou actually i am new to jquery, can u please tell me how to do that and also i have a doubt, if we disable the button, can we enable it back when user reupload the files to correctlimit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will implement the disable attribute strategy as I said in the comments:

```
$("#myfile").on("change", function() {
if ($("#myfile")[0].files.length > 4) {
    alert("You can select only 4 images");
    $(".form-control").prop("disabled",true);
 } 
});
```

With the above code the user will not be able to submit the form

Comment: i tried this, this is disabling the button, but how can i enable it back when user reuploads the correct number of files

Comment: if i add an else like  else{
   $("#thatbutton").prop("disabled",false);
 } , will it have any issue

Comment: @Adheednihal probably not...this is what I was going to suggest anyway...I just did not tested it...but if it works then probably you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

In this case better to create one more variable with flag status and then check it before submit a form.

Something like that:

```
let flag = false;

$("#myfile").on("change", function() {
    if ($("#myfile")[0].files.length > 4) {
        alert("You can select only 4 images");
        flag = true;
    }
});

if(!flag){
    $('#form').submit();
}
```

Comment: this is making the page reload automatically multiple times without stopping

Comment: @Adheednihal For sure. You should make a event listener on Submit button. In my opinion better to make just a button or even span with id and add event listener on click for it. In this case you will be checking this flag only after clicking. Also you could combine this solutions with solution below with disabling button.